# breaking out of a do..while event loop running in another thread

Tags: c, multithreading

```
gcc 4.7.2
c89
```

Hello,

I am trying to stop an event loop that is running inside a worker thread.

I control the while loop with a condition in a structure from another function. However, the value doesn't seem to change. It doesn't go into the switch statement condition IMP_STATE_STOPPED so cannot set the condition to false to stop the do..while loop.

The imp structure is something like this:

```
enum states_e {IMP_STATE_STARTED, IMP_STATE_STOPPED};
struct imp_t {
    states_e state;
};
```

This is what I have - only essential snippets only:
worker thread function with event loop this will just spin round until the `is_looping` changes to false

```
static void* g_imp_evt_loop(apr_thread_t *thd, void *data)
{
    imp_t *imp = NULL;
    volatile apr_status_t is_looping = TRUE;

    imp = (imp_t*)data;
    if(!imp) {
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("[ %p ]", imp);

#define SR_TIMEOUT 500

    do {
        if(waitevt(SR_TIMEOUT) >= 0) {
            switch(imp->state) {
            case IMP_STATE_STARTED:
            {
                /* do some work */
            }
            break;

            case IMP_STATE_STOPPED:
                is_looping = FALSE;
                break;
            }

            apr_sleep(250000);
        }
    } while(is_looping);

    return NULL;
}
```

This is the snippet where I start my worker thread which is called from another function:

```
void start_working(imp_t *imp)
{
    printf("[ %p ]\n", imp);

    if(apr_thread_pool_schedule(imp->module->thd_pool,
                                g_imp_evt_loop,
                                (void*)imp,
                                0, /* Start now */
                                NULL) != APR_SUCCESS) {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

And in my stopping function I set the condition in the imp structure to `IMP_STATE_STOPPED`.

```
void stop_working(imp_t *imp)
{
    printf("[ %p ]\n", imp);
    imp->state = IMP_STATE_STOPPED;
}
```

Could it be that data is local to that worker thread function that I cannot change it?

I printed out the addresses in each function and all the adddress are the same for imp i.e. `0x923b710`

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: is waitevt(SR_TIMEOUT) >= 0?

Comment: @ heikkim, I think the waitevt is blocking until it receives an event. However, I thought it would timeout if it didn't receive a event within the timeout period (500 ms)

Comment: What happen if waitevt() returns -1 ?

Comment: I have changed the source code so that the switch is outside of the waitevt. Seems to work ok this way. So it has to check the condition in the switch first before calling the waitevt for each loop of the do..while.

Comment: Also just in case I would define `imp` as `volatile imp_t *imp`. You do not need `volatile` on `is_looping` though because the compiler can see that it is being modified within the loop. `volatile` only means that that variable is subject to (external) changes that are not obvious for the compiler and it should not be cached in registers, but reloaded from memory on every access.